# Is the image of the map $A \to \bigwedge^{k}A $ a weakly embedded submanifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, real-algebraic-geometry, exterior-algebra

$\newcommand{\End}{\operatorname{End}}$
$\newcommand{\GL}{\operatorname{GL}}$
Let $V$ be a $d$-dimensional **real** vector space. ($d \ge 4$). Fix an **odd** $2 \le k \le d-2$. Define
$H_{>k}=\{ A \in \End(V) \mid \operatorname{rank}(A) > k 
\}$. $H_{>k}$ is an open submanifold of $\End(V)$.

We also define, for a given number $s$, the open submanifold

$$\tilde H_{>s}=\{ B \in \End(\bigwedge^k V) \mid \operatorname{rank}(B) > s 
\} \subseteq \End(\bigwedge^k V).$$

Consider the map
$$
\psi:H_{>k} \to \tilde H_{>k} \, \,, \, \, \psi(A)=\bigwedge^{k}A,
%\psi:H_r \to \text{End}(\bigwedge^{k}V) \, \,, \, \, \psi(A)=\bigwedge^{k}A,
$$

$\psi$ is a **smooth injective immersion but not an embedding**. (The injectivity uses the fact $k$ is odd, since otherwise $\psi(A)=\psi(-A)$).

> **Question:** Is $\text{Image}(\psi)=\psi(H_{>k})$ a weakly embedded submanifold of $\tilde H_{>k}$?

Note that the image is not closed. The reason is that the rank can fall in the limit to an "illegal value"- a value which is not obtainable by exterior powers of endomorphisms of $V$.

Weakly embedded here means that for every manifold $Q$ and for every smooth map $h:Q \to \tilde H_{>k}$, with $h(Q)\subset \psi(H_{>k})$,the associated map $h:Q\to \psi(H_{>k})$ is also smooth. In other words, it's always valid to restrict the range.

(Some authors call "weakly embedded" submanifolds, *initial submanifolds*, or *diffeological submanifolds*).

It is known that it suffices to prove that $h:Q\to \psi(H_{>k})$ is continuous.

---

Of course, $ \psi(H_{>k})$ is an immersed submanifold, but it is not an embedded submanifold, since $\psi$ is not an embedding (I prove this at the end).

*Here are some more thoughts:*

1. *Using group actions and equivariance:*

There is a natural action on $H_{>k}$ by $\GL(V) \times \GL(V)$, given by
$$
(A,B) \cdot C=ACB^{-1}.
$$

This action has a finite number of orbits; each orbit is the set of matrices of a certain rank. There is also a $\GL(V) \times \GL(V)$-action on  $\End(\bigwedge^k V)$, given by
$$
(A,B) \cdot D=\bigwedge^k A \circ D \circ \bigwedge^k B^{-1}.
$$
$\psi$ is equivariant w.r.t these actions. This might brings us close to the solution, but it's still not enough:

If the action was transitive on the source manifold $H_{>k}$, we were done: The image would then be the orbit of a Lie group action, [which is always weakly embedded](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0011241).

However, in our case the action is not transitive, so this argument cannot be applied directly. Indeed, there are equivariant maps, where the sources has finitely many orbits, [whose images are not weakly embedded](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816829/is-the-image-of-an-equivariant-map-always-a-weakly-embedded-submanifold).

2. *Using the "stratified/filtered" structure:*

Let $H_{i}=\{ A \in \End(V) \mid \operatorname{rank}(A) = i 
\}$, and $\tilde H_i$ its analog on the exterior algebra $\bigwedge^kV$.

For $A \in \text{End}(V)$,
 $$\operatorname{rank}(\bigwedge^kA) = \binom {\operatorname{rank}(A)}{k} ,$$  that is $\psi(H_r) \subseteq \tilde H_{\binom {r}{k}}$.

[Each restriction $\psi|_{H_r}:H_r \to \tilde H_{\binom {r}{k}}$ is proper](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2819477/104576), hence $\psi(H_r)$ is an embedded submanifold, and we have $\psi(H_{>k})=\cup_{i=k+1}^d \psi(H_r)$.

The problem is that union of embedded submanifolds does not need to be weakly embedded in general.

---

Finally, note that in the case $k=d-1$, the answer is positive, since then $\psi:\text{GL}(V) \to \text{GL}(\bigwedge^k V) $ is proper.

---

*Here is a proof showing $\psi$ is not an embedding:*

Take $d=4,k=2$:

Let $A=\text{diag}(1,1,1,0) \in \text{End}( V)$. Then $\bigwedge^2 A =\text{diag}(1,1,1,0,0,0) \in \text{End}( \bigwedge^2 V)$.
Let $B_r(A) \in H_{>2}$ be an open ball. Assume by contradiction  $\psi(B_r(A))$ is open in $\tilde H_{>2}$; there exist an open set $U \subseteq \text{End}( \bigwedge^2 V)$  such that $\psi(B_r(A))=\tilde H_{>2} \cap U$.
Define
$A_n=\text{diag}(n,\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n},\frac{1}{n}) $.

Then $\psi(A_n)=\bigwedge^2 A_n =\text{diag}(1,1,1,\frac{1}{n^2},\frac{1}{n^2},\frac{1}{n^2}) \in \tilde H_{>2} \cap U=\psi(B_r(A))$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Since $\psi$ is locally injective ($\psi(A)=\psi(B) \Rightarrow A=\pm B$), this implies $A_n$ or $-A_n$ lies in $B_r(A)$ for every sufficiently large $n$. This is a contradiction.

*I required $k$ to be odd, but this example can be easily adapted to the odd case.

---

*Indeed, here is an example for the case $k$ is odd:*

Set $d=6,k=3$: Take $A=\text{diag}(1,1,1,1,1,0) \in \text{End}( V)$. Then $\bigwedge^3 A =\text{diag}(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0) \in \text{End}( \bigwedge^3 V)$. Take $A_n=\text{diag}(n,\frac{1}{\sqrt n},\frac{1}{\sqrt n},\frac{1}{\sqrt n},\frac{1}{\sqrt n},\frac{1}{\sqrt n})$. Now the same argument as above applies.

Comment: Here is an earlier published source of the fact that an orbit of a Lie group action is always initial: 5.14 (based on 3.20 which shows that leaves of integrable distributions of non-constant rank are always initial) in http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/kmsbookh.pdf